# How to make select statement return rows have comma separated from field?

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, sql-function

I work on SQL server 2012 I face issue:I can't make select statement

return only rows have comma separated from field  ValueHaveComma ?

I need to do

```
select * from #seachvaluesHaveComma where ValueHaveComma contain comma
```

my sample as below

```
create table #seachvaluesHaveComma
(
ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
ValueHaveComma nvarchar(100)
)
insert into #seachvaluesHaveComma(ValueHaveComma)
 values 
 ('1,2'),
 ('3.5,5.4'),
 ('a,b,c'),
 ('A')
```

Expected result as :

```
ID  ValueHaveComma
1   1,2
2   3.5,5.4
3   a,b,c
```

Comment: `select * from #seachvaluesHaveComma where ValueHaveComma like '%,%'`. But you should never, **ever**, store comma separated values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the results in two ways,

`CHARINDEX`

```
select * from #seachvaluesHaveComma where CHARINDEX(ValueHaveComma, ',') > 0;
```

`LIKE`

```
select * from #seachvaluesHaveComma where ValueHaveComma like '%,%';
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this query. this is simple query to get value having comma. WE need to use Like operator because you mentioned sql server.

```
select * from #seachvaluesHaveComma where ValueHaveComma like '%,%'
```